# install SSMSE 2008 after VS 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have installed VS 2010 ultimate on windows 7 machine which by default install sql server 2008. now i want to install SSMSE 2008 i download the following file SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU and tried to install it but it give me error.

---

[Window Title]
Program Compatibility Assistant

[Main Instruction]
This program has known compatibility issues

[Expanded Information]
After SQL Server Setup completes, you must apply SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 (SP1) or a later service pack before you run SQL Server 2008 on this version of Windows.

[^] Hide details  [ ] Don't show this message again  [Check for solutions online] [Run program] [Cancel]

---

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created..

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

---

how to install SSMSE 2008 after installing VS 2010 please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [slipstream](http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/02/25/sql-server-2008-creating-a-merged-slisptream-drop.aspx) the SQL 2008 SP1 before installing SQL 2008. The linked article explains how to do that.

An easier workaround is to first install the [SQL Server 2008 SP1 package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20302) or [SQL Server 2008 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12548). The SP1 install will fail, since there is no SQL Server installation to patch, but in the process it will deploy newer setup bits that have the Invoke/BeginInvoke issue fixed. Afterwards you run the normal RTM setup and it will succeed, as it will re-use the newer setup bits already present on the machine from the SP1 instalation. After the installation of SQL Server 2008 RTM succeeds, you still needs to apply SP1 or SP2.

If you're attempting to install SQL Server 2008 Express you should install directly the SP2 bits: [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP2 Express Edition Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20610), or better yet [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 - Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729). The 2008 R2 Express has the database [size limit increased to 10Gb](http://rusanu.com/2010/04/28/sql-server-2008-r2-express-database-size-limit-10gb/).

Comment: hi i am trying to install SQL management studio express (SSMSE) and not SQL server 2008

Comment: Not a big fan of "I will not post until" statements. Remember, he's not the only one looking for an answer. If you know an easier/simpler method, help out the community by posting it.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar situation, The workaround I tried is,

1)Fire up the Sql Server installation Center from
(start->programs-> Microsoft SQL  server 2008-> Configuration Tools)

2)Click on installation(from the navigation menu on the left)

3)Choose the first option(New server installation)

4)A new dialog will appear, click next till you reach 'installation type' screen. Choose new installation here

5)Click next till you reach feature selection, make sure you have ticked Management tools checkbox.

6)Continue installation and if it completes successfully, you can find the SSMSE in the start menu under Microsoft sql server 2008 folder.
Hope this helps.